# Running and staying in a ksh subshell

Tags: shell, ksh, aix

Subshell might not be the correct term.  Let me try to explain.

If I log into my account and I'm sitting at the ksh93 shell prompt, I can type "ksh93" which puts me in a 'subshell' where I can enter more command.  When I'm done in the subshell I type exit which returns me to the shell prompt in the original shell.

If I'm sitting at the ksh93 shell prompt and type "ksh93 ls" it spawns the subshell, runs the ls command, then returns to the parent shell.  How can get the subshell to run the passed command but then stay in the subshell (ie: don't return to the parent shell until exit is entered)?

Thanks.

Comment: u can take a look at tools like [tag:expect] or [tag:pexpect]

Comment: I'm surprised there isn't a flag that can be passed to instruct the subshell to remain active when a command is passed.